# DataGrid Validation.Error Not Called

Tags: wpf, validation, binding, datagrid

When SelectedItem.DT throws an error Validation_Error is not called?   DT is a DataTable from a SQL query and I want to display the SQL error if the TSQL fails.   I guess I could build a DataTable and put the ex.msg in the table.  But I would rather call Validation_Error.

```
    <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" AutoGenerateColumns="True"  
              ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=cbReports, Path=SelectedItem.DT, ValidatesOnExceptions=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}"
              Validation.Error="Validataion_Error" />
```

This TextBox (on another page) does call Validation_Error when an error is thrown in set.

```
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=DF.FieldValue, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnExceptions=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True}"
             Validation.Error="Validataion_Error"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx) is not implement [IDataErrorInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.idataerrorinfo.aspx) then it isn't do any validation error automatically for you. I always transform DataTable to [ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) of my class that implement IDataErrorInfo.

```
public class MyClass : IDataErrorInfo
{
    //..
}

// Use ObservableCollection instead of DataTable
ObservableCollection<MyClass> MyDataGridItemsSource { get; set; }
```

I guess that the reason your textbox binding works is `DF` in your `DF.FieldValue` is implement `IDataErrorInfo`.

Comment: Thanks, how do I transform a DataTable to an ObservableCollection?

Comment: I suggest you to use AutoMapper (http://automapper.org/), otherwise you need to create method and copy data by yourself.